# Find encoding that encodes a given character to a given sequence

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to find out which encoding uses some text file I have received. I know that this encoding encodes [é](https://unicode-table.com/en/00E9/) to 0x8E.

Specific question: which encodings possibly correspond?

General question: how can I find out, in general, which encodings match some constraints expressed as pairs of (unicode character, byte sequence)?

uchardet does not help: it detects windows-1252 but that is obviously incorrect in my case. Generally speaking, such tool will do a poorer job at detecting encodings compared to using constraints as external knowledge.

I understand that conceptually, any encoding may be conceived that encodes é to 0x8E and anything else to anything else, but I want to search only among encodings generally used by human kind. (Specifically, in this case, probably some encoding generally used in the western European world.)

I suspect this could be done using, e.g., data files from uchardet, with clever use of grep or similar tools. Preferably the tools involved would be free as in free speech and available on standard GNU-Linux distributions.

Comment: People at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281069/find-encoding-that-encodes-a-given-character-to-a-given-sequence pointed you to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, not to Super User... I'm not sure this is on topic there, but it's off topic here, just like on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote there: “Actually I suspect Super User might be a better fit, as I expect an answer is possible by combining some existing tools or even using some web site.” Why is it off topic here?

Comment: _"I am looking for some web site (web service) that ..."_

Comment: Oops. Edited to match requirements. (Actually I first thought about command line tools, only when writing the question did it come to my mind that a web site might partly solve the problem as well. But it would in any case be an imperfect solution.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic it belongs on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Hurry, the Bounties are coming, the Bounties are coming!!

Comment: If you wonder why, say no more.... classic example as per your own wording to be exact, but not limited to; "***I am looking for a tool or a combination of tools that would do the job***"

Comment: I do not understand your reference to "I am looking for a tool or a combination of tools that would do the job". I just searched for this on super user and super user meta, to no avail.
Besides, there’s most probably not an existing software that solves this specific problem. Although, the problem is probably solvable with a bit of grepping and combining the right tools. I view it as similar to, for example, asking for a way to rename all files in a folder that starts with such or such characters.
https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7458/at-what-point-do-regexes-become-programming-questions

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I believe then the phrasing of my question might be wrong. I am not trying to find a software that solves the problem (I’d be very surprised if that existed out of the box). I expect an answer to contain some use of, say, sed, grep, together with, perhaps, files used by uchardet or other similar software as "database". Would you consider that asking for a way to rename all files in a folder that starts with such or such characters is software shopping?

Comment: Don't say that you are "looking for a tool or a combination of tools that would do the job" but instead show us what you are currently doing, what you are trying to achieve and any research you have done. Until your final sentences are removed and your question elaborated on this sounds very much like you are looking for a recommendation of some random software to do your job.

Comment: I just tried another phrasing. I honestly still do not understand how my question differs from asking for a way to rename all files in a folder that starts with such or such characters.
About research I have done: I attempted to use uchardet, searched on Super User and related websites, and searched for software or web page to do exactly that, and didn’t find any (as expected). I have written about uchardet already in my OP.

Comment: `mac_greek`, `mac_iceland`, `mac_latin2`, `mac_roman`, `mac_turkish` from the following very simple _python_ script: `import codecs;char_u = u'é';
char_e = b'\x8e';
for cod in codec_list:
    if (codecs.encode( char_u,encoding=cod,errors='replace') == char_e):
        print( char_u, char_e, cod);` where `codec_list` is defined as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584253/3439404

Comment: Great! I didn’t know that list, very useful indeed. Now I only have to generalize that code for any number of constraints, which should be easy.